# Publish editor add-on to G Suite Marketplace as internal (domain only) app for G suite

Tags: google-forms, google-apps-script-addon

I developed a Google Form add-on and tried to publish it in the G Suite Marketplace as private (only for my G Suite domain) by following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons).

I did this more than 2 days ago and the add-on is still not visible in the G Suite Marketplace, but the guide says:

> If you selected Private visibility for the add-on, the add-on should become available for use after a few minutes.

So I think there is some issue here.

Earlier in October, the guide was different as the publication in Chrome web store was also required. The new guide has no more steps to publish to this Chrome Web Store so I did not do this.

Here are some ideas of the root cause of my issue (the fact that it's not visible in G Suite Marketplace):

1. Chrome web store is still required (but the guide says it's no more required). I have some doubt as this guide has been changed a couple of weeks ago.
2. In G Suite Marketplace SDK, the "publish" tab is may be also required? But the guide explains only the "Configuration" tab. Is this "publish" tab now required?
3. The guide is wrong?
4. I need to wait more time?

My guess is that the root cause is number 2. I guess the "publish" tab is required but the guide does not require this

### Edit

When I was typing this issue here, [the user guide was updated](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons). Now I see that it's again required to publish the app to the Chrome Web Store, this has just been added : "Step 5: Configure the Chrome Web Store listing and publish".

Answer (score 0):

It seems the [user guide](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons) has been updated again, there is no more step 5.

I manage to get my private add-on available as a domain app after "forcing" the configuration page to save new settings. Here is how.

After the migration, the configuration page was set up but the publish page only show this message

> Please setup 'Configuration' tab before publishing.

But on the configuration page, the save button was disabled as all the fields have been imported from CWS.

To enable the save button, I only had to change the privacy policy URL with a new one and save.

After that, the publish page showed the classic settings and I was able to publish the add-on. It appears on the GSuite Marketplace [Domain App](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/mydomainapps?hl=en&pann=sheets_addon_widget) a few minutes after that.

I hope it helps.

In addition, but you may have done it already, the project is [attached to my organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing) in GCP and it is [marked as internal-only](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914)